# Creating a simple jQuery game to predict a winner

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

I am trying to create this game, right now it shows 8 teams and the user has to click on them and selected teams comes to next zone until there is one winner. I have created teams in pair from an array but not able to build a logic to select team which goes to next level. I will share the code written so far.

It’s a coin toss code where it picks between 0 and 1 which determines the winner.

Code - http://plnkr.co/edit/sTzLPlSbyXPCA0mpWkdC?p=preview

This is the code that I have attempted so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var btTeams = ['Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team D', 'Team E', 'Team F', 'Team G', 'Team H'],
    _html = "";

  $.each(btTeams, function(intIndex, objValue) {

    if ((intIndex + 1) % 2 !== 0) {
      _html += '<ul class="bt-zone-pair" data-team="team' + intIndex + '">';
    }

    // Add li for all cases
    _html += '<li class="bt-zone"><a href="javscript:void(0)">' +
      objValue + "</a></li>";

    if ((intIndex + 1) % 2 === 0) {
      _html += "</ul>"
    }
  });

  $('.bt-col1').append(_html);

});
```

The greatest difficulty I'm having at the moment is creating a common logic to map teams to next level to choose winner.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What currently works? Can the user currently click to select winners, while you are looking for a way to automate this? The plunker code currently does not work as far as I can see.

Comment: Plukr won't work as of now. I have started putting code into that but I need guidance on how to implement this code. For ex. someone suggest me to use multidimensional array to keep the selected teams. But i have never used multidimensional array till date. I am looking for a pattern on how to implement the code to build this game.

Comment: I think you'd have an easier time if each `bt-zone-pair` as well as each team had it's own `id` attribute. Also, the structure is not consistent between heats. For example, the first heat has 8 teams and 4 `bt-zone-pair` blocks, however the second heat has only 4 teams and still uses 4 `bt-zone-pairs`. Edit this a bit and let's see where we can take it from there.

Comment: Code is updated on plunkr and it is working now. Facing few issues, first, on multiple clicks, team blocks starts stacking in random order. Second, if i click team F for first time, it gets stacked on top. Can you help me to resolve these bugs?